# Raw Sockets in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

1.

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
```

The linux manual page says about this code.

In socket option, if IP_HDRINCL is set, I can make IP header. Am I right?
If it's right, above socket also let me make TCP header, too?

Then, if IP_HDRINCL is not set, what means above socket?

2.

```
 socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
 socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
```

what means above code comparing to number 1 question's code?

I know IPPROTO_RAW can't receive any IP packets. And here, these sockets only can receive TCP packets, and UDP pakcets each.(Can I see IP Header, Ethernet Header also?)
But how about sending?? I don'know exactly about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. IP_HDRINCL means: I want my data (for send and recv) to include the ip hdr. And if your data include the ip hdr, it means that the tcp hdr follows (just after the ip hdr), and finally the app's message too (the message your normally give to send ...). Without IP_HDRINCL, you have access to apps data only.
2. Yes, IPPROTO_TCP and IPPROTO_UDP whith SOCK_RAW are just filters as you say, for sending **and** receiving. Use IPPROTO_RAW to be able to send any TCP/IP packet (no filter). But to also receive packets, you need also to change AF_INET into AF_PACKET.

Comment: Can I see ethernet, IP, tcp/udp headers from number 2's question's socket when i receive packet from these socekts? And about sending, number 2's question's socket, if I use IPPROTO_TCP, then I only can make IP header and, TCP header? and If I use IPPROTO_UDP, then I can only make IP header and UDP header? So If I use IPROTO_RAW, then I can make make any TP layers header?

Comment: Yes, you do see these headers

Comment: Then, what's different between socket(af_inet, sock_raw, IPPROTO_TCP) and socket(af_packet, sock_raw, IPPROTO_TCP) when receiving packets? I think they both can get packets from link layer to app layer. Are they just different when sending packets because of latter can make ethernet header?

Comment: The INET in AF_INET means Internet i.e. TCP/IP. Internet (TCP/IP) doesn't care about your link layer, it is not part of Internet. So AF_INET = IP layer, and AF_PACKET = link layer. You don't have access to link layer with AF_INET.

Comment: @mikedu95 No all statements are not correct. an AF_INET, SOCK_RAW socket does not give you access to ethernet , or whatever is below the IP layer. AF_PACKET sockets does.

Comment: @nos I don't see any reference to ethernet in comment #1. And in case of misunderstanding, comment #5 says exactly what you are saying right now.